# Annotations/approach for ingress configurations via helm

Tags: kubernetes-helm, nginx-ingress, nginx-config

For my application in AKS with nginx as ingress, I tried adding the below in ingress.yaml

nginx.org/server-tokens: "false"
nginx.io/x-frame-options: DENY
nginx.org/rewrites: ^/privacy-policy /index.html last;
nginx.org/rewrites: ^/account-(.*) /index.html last;

nginx.org/rewrites: ^/consignee-(.*) /index.html last;
nginx.org/rewrites: ^/notification-(.*) /index.html last;

nginx.org/rewrites: ^/admin-(.*) /index.html last;
customErrorPages:
502:
url: https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/customerror/502.html
503:
url: https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/customerror/502.html

But looks like these are not at all considered.
Am I doing this correctly? If not, Can anyone please throw some light over these please.